# 20.04 LTS Server fails to install but Desktop version installs

Tags: system-installation

New installation
MOBO X570 Aorus Ultra with wifi module removed.

The 20.04LTS and 20.10 Server fail to install - they generate a VERY LENGTHY report towards the end of the installation process but the system is never installed.

However, the 20.04 LTS desktop installed with ease.

AMD RYZEN 5 3600 processor 64GB RAM two 1TB hard drives no RAID

Tried various partition setups including the default, no luck?

Very inexperienced with Linux

My goal is to create a small business server, MYSQL, email server, Apache web server, and SVN server.

I can try and change the desktop into a server (like the idea of keeping the desktop) but concerned about security and performance.

Or

Keep retrying to install Server - my gut tells me something is not correct in the BIOS regarding the Hard Drives.

The desktop version is working great - drives fine, LAN, mouse, Keyboard, tested many program everything works.

Any clues?

Comment: If you would like to use a GUI to manager your server, stick with the desktop installation and be sure to disable all power saving features except for shutting the display off. Ubuntu Desktop will run Apache, MySQL, and everything else just fine. With regards to security, it is just as dependable as the Server installation.

Comment: Please file a bug report for the failed Ubuntu Server install. Attach the VERY LENGTHY report to the bug report

Comment: Moving from the server edition to the desktop one doesn't make your system more insecure.  The two are pretty much the same.  They just choose a different subset of packages (i.e., the desktop edition has a desktop, the server one does not).  If the desktop version works, stick to that and don't stress yourself with the server edition.  Then, add/remove software to fit your taste.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. After reading user535733 suggestion last night I decided to re-install the Server edition so I could generate the lengthy report and send in a bug report to help others in the future. To my surprise, the server installed. Somehow, installing the desktop version first fixed the problem. Since I know how to get around the issue now, I am going to pull the drives and replace them with new ones (I have extras) and try to recreate the problem. Will post my results soon.

Comment: I could not access the disks to copy and send the report, and the installation USB apparently does not contain a copy of the report. I tried some other methods to retrieve the file off the drives, but I was not able to access the drives at all. One last bit of information: When I tried the installation with ONE drive only, the Server installation was successful. The issue is related to the fact that two drives are present. It must be BIOS/ BIOS settings and something unique to Ubuntu Server, since 20.04 Desktop installed with one or TWO drives present.

Comment: If someone runs into the same issue, install Desktop and add what you need to get your job done. If you insist on installing the Server version, I was able to install it AFTER installing Desktop first.
Thanks for your help
Alphamoose